# Table lock issue while using sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am facing Table Lock issues when getting rows in Parent & child case.

The scenario is below:

TBL_COMMON  1--------------1 TABLE-1 
TBL_COMMON  1--------------1 TABLE-2

1. While inserting a record in **TABLE1**, as a validation step we check entry exist in **TBL_COMMON**. So one select operation performed.
2. If succeed, insert operation is performed.

Everything executed in one method call.

Sometimes **TBL_COMMON** Table is get locked.

This issue does not occur every time but didn't know the actual reason.

Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using MyISAM for TBL_COMMON? If so, can you try to change that to InnoDB?

InnoDB has row level locking.

Comment: Hi Viam, for all tables, I am using InnoDB engine.